# pygame.time.clock() or pygame.clock.tick() error

Tags: python, pygame

I have a main loop in my code where it loops everything and when I run my code I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Javier\Documents\Python Pygame\First Game\First 
    Game.py", line 17, in <module>
        clock=pygame.time.clock()
    AttributeError: module 'pygame.time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

I understand what the error is: it means it can't find the 'class' `clock` and in another instance where I used `pygame.tick.clock()` I got the same error.

```
    #import modules here

    import pygame

    #define what colours are
    black=(0,0,0)
    white=(255,255,255)
    turquoise=(64,224,208)
    #initalise pygame
    pygame.init()
    #set up screen
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
    #what the screen is called and backgroud colour
    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Snake!")
    #set a variable for how quick the game runs
    clock=pygame.time.clock()

    '''making future references easier
    eval just takes code as a string and runs it
    eg:
    instead of doing print(5+8)
    you can do eval(print(5+8))'''
    def key(key):
        return pygame.ket.get_pressed()[eval("pygame.K_"+key)]
    #draw the snake
    snake=(50,150,150,50)
    #display.flip shows what has been drawn on the screen eg the snake
    while True:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,turquoise,snake)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
```

When I comment the problem code (`clock.tick()` and `pygame.time.clock`)  the window opens and displays the turquoise "snake" but it has no limiting factor that slows down the rate of the loop executing.

Comment: If you select the green check mark by the best answer, it will be marked as accepted.  You can also upvote it along with any other answers you liked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go figure but documenation says it's

```
pygame.time.Clock
```

note the uppercase C in clock vs lowercase.

Answer (score 4):

To use the pygame clock:

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

Then,

```
clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's `pygame.time.Clock` and `pygame.time.Clock.tick`

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock

As you noted, the module couldn't find the class `Clock`.  In Python, the convention for Classes is to capitalize them.